# Sequential Column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Having a simple query such as:

```
select * from foo
```

Where the output has the columns

```
bar | abc | def
---------------
...............
```

It is possible to encapsulate this query into another one and give sequential names instead to the columns such as `1|2|3...` (mantaining all the rows intact)?

I know this sounds weird and probably it isn't even possible.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint:  `select bar as [1], abc as [2], def as [3] . . . `.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the "main" query is variable and dynamic, I never know what columns it will contain so the directly applying aliases don't really work :)

Comment: @DiogoSantos in that case add the aliases in the query construction code. `select *` doesn't really exist. It's parsed into specific columns, ie `select bar,abc,def` before execution

Comment: Any update? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100) = 'YOUR TABLENAME HERE',
    @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '

SELECT @Query = CONCAT(@Query, '    ', COLUMN_NAME, ' AS ', QUOTENAME(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION)), ', 
')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName

SET @Query = SUBSTRING(@Query, 0, LEN(@Query) - 3) + ' 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
```

You use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to get all our table's columns, 
ROW_NUMBER() window function to generate sequential number for column aliases and sp_ExecuteSQL to execute dynamic generated queries.

Comment: This wouldn't give the correct result. With the names `bar`, `abc`, and `def` the columns would be named `2`, `1` and `3` respectively. The OP wants them to be `1`, `2`, and `3` respectively

Comment: Edited so the ROW_NUMBER sorts by ORDINAL_POSITION which is the order of the columns in the table.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. I would, also, however, quote the name of `@TableName`; unless you want to suffer injection. (Hint `'[' + @TableName + ']'` is **not** properly quoting the object's name, as the right Bracket (`]`) can easily be escaped: `SET @TableName = N'table]; CREATE LOGIN ... ;--`.).

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max),
        @TableName VARCHAR(100) = '<YourTableName>'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT  DENSE_RANK()OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) Rno,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_CATALOG='Database' 
AND TABLE_NAME =  @TableName
) 
SELECT 'SELECT '+ STUFF((SELECT ', '+ COLUMN_NAME +' AS '+ QUOTENAME(CAST(Rno AS VARCHAR))
FROM CTE
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') + ' FROM '+@TableName 
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```